# React D3 : JSON file is not getting loaded , Promise, 404 error

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, promise, react-redux

In My App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as d3queue from 'd3-queue';
import * as topojson from 'topojson';

var usState = require("./us-states.json");
var usCounty = require("./us-counties.json");

var imageModule=new ImageModule(imageOpts);
var queue = d3queue.queue();

var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
  super();
  this.drawDoc = this.drawDoc.bind(this);
  }

  drawState(){
     queue.defer(d3.csv, dataCsv , function (d) {
       console.log("d" , d);
             return {
                 id: +(d.state + d.county),
                 state: d.state,
                 county: d.county,
                 unemployment: +d.unemployment
             }
         }.bind(this))
         .defer(d3.json, './us-states.json', {
         headers : {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
         })
         .defer(d3.json, './us-counties.json', {
         headers : {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
         })
         .awaitAll(this.initializeIt)
  }

  initializeIt(error, results) {
      if (error) { throw error }
      var data = results[0]
}
}
```

The json file is not getting loaded and i am getting the following error like "Uncaught (in promise) {state: "01", county: "000", name: "Alabama", unemployment: "0.061"}" and 404 error while loading the json file.

Comment: Second argument of d3.json is a callback function. You're passing an object.

Comment: @KyleRichardson , even if i remove the second object , still it doesnot work .

Comment: Just curious, is your json formatted like that? If so it is not valid json. It's javascript object syntax. If that is your json format, wrap the keys in quotes as well.

Comment: @KyleRichardson No, the json is not formatted like that. It is a valid JSON object.